# Laravel 5.2 validation fails when parameters value missing or equal symbol missing

Tags: php, laravel, request

Have a request
`/web/v1/documents/?date=2019-05-22&sort=category`

contrtoller:

```
$sort   = $request->get('sort', 'commodity');
```

This value is optional and here validation:

**DocumentsReportRequest:**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'sort' => ['in:commodity,category'],
    ];
}
```

if request
`/web/v1/documents/?date=2019-05-22&sort`
or
`/web/v1/documents/?date=2019-05-22&sort=`

Validation rule does not work and i got error.

Is there a way to validate parameters in this case?

Comment: You could try checking to see if sort is set, then if it is, add the rule to the rules array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `nullable` or `sometimes` rule to your validation, like this:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'sort' => ['nullable', 'in:commodity,category'],
    ];
}
```

Or `present` which requires the key to exist in the request but it can be empty.

Comment: did you really? So you say there is an error in the framework? This is what I use, it is documented as well.

Comment: i think, my framework version(5.2)    

Method [validateNullable] does not exist.

Comment: nope, the `nullable` field exists before that. I had version 5.2 till recently. What is the error that you get back?

Comment: BadMethodCallException in Validator.php line 3295:
Method [validateNullable] does not exist.

Comment: Oh, wow. Then try to use the `present` rule instead. But keep in mind that this will require the `sort` key to exist in the request but it can be empty

Comment: @Dimas if it works please consider accepting the answer, I updated it.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation

Comment: There is no reputation needed for marking an answer to your question as accepted. There is a checkmark near the vote arrows that you can click. You can also upvote any question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nullable` validation if the parameter is not always available

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'sort' => ['nullable','in:commodity,category'],
    ];
}
```